# Limit csv column length using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, truncate

I'm trying to adjust a tab-delimited textfile *without headers* using PowerShell and have it write the output to the same tab-delimited textfile. Currently source data is as follows;

- AAA \t  BBBBBB \t CCCCCCCCCCC
- AAAA \t BBBB \t AAAABBBBBCCCCCCC

Now column number three should be limited to the first 5 characters only, making the output look as follows;

- AAA \t  BBBBBB \t CCCCC
- AAAA \t BBBB \t AAAAB

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will import a CSV file using `Import-Csv` and then loop through all the lines, creating a substring (5 in length) of the 3rd column before writing the line into a new CSV file.

```
$oldCSV = "T:\OLD.csv"
$newCSV = "T:\New.csv" 

Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Path $oldCSV -Header "1","2","3" | ForEach-Object { 
    "{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f $_.1,$_.2,($_.3).Substring(0,[Math]::Min(5,($_.3).Length)) >> $newCSV 
}
```

Comment: It'll get upset if there are quoted values to handle in any of the remaining fields as well; not necessarily expected here, but a limitation nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Truncate it after importing:

```
Import-Csv ... | ForEach-Object { if ($_.Column3.Length -gt 5) { $_.Column3.Substring(0, 5) }; $_ }
```

If you wished to apply the rule across all properties you might create a generic property loop instead of targeting a specific property by name.

```
Import-Csv ... | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        if ($property.Value.Length -gt 5) {
            $property.Value = $property.Value.Substring(0, 5)
        }
    }
    $_
}
```

Import-Csv itself won't do that for you, it's not the job it's trained for.

Comment: Apologies, more haste less speed. A fix will be along in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your own header information to `Import-Csv`:

```
# Import the file with the proper delimiter and dummy headings
(Import-Csv foo.tsv -delim "`t" -header c1,c2,c3) |
  # Truncate the third column accordingly. Regex because I'm lazy.
  ForEach-Object { $_.c3 = $_.c3 -replace '(?<=^.{5}).*'; $_ } |
  # Convert back to TSV. This also emits the headers
  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -delim "`t" |
  # Remove the headers again
  Select -Skip 1 |
  # Write back to file
  Out-File foo.tsv -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use positive look-behind. An alternative: `-replace '^(.{5}).*', '$1'`

Comment: @ChrisDent: I know, I just tend to avoid replacing text with itself when I can help it.  Call it a habit :-)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working, I'm ending up with an empty file. Tried with Chris' fix as well. What could be going wrong?

Comment: @user58602: Fixed; the ForEach-Object didn't return anything and just ate all the data. Also we need to make sure to read the file completely before the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

A better modular approach would be to pipeline the modified object to the `Export-Csv` commandlet.

```
$charLimit=100
Import-Csv "$_" -Delimiter "`t" | ForEach-Object {
   $_."column 1" = $_."column 1".Substring(0,[Math]::Min($charLimit,($_.'column 1').Length))
   $_."column 2" = $_."column 2".Substring(0,[Math]::Min($charLimit,($_.'column 2').Length))
   Write-Output $_
} | Export-Csv $targetfile -NoTypeInformation
```

In the above code snippet `Write-Output` will pass down the modified object to the pipeline. This will be faster than writing while modifing as the Export-Csv will handle the file outputs better than that.